# How can I add fastlane builds to Xcode's archive organizer?

Tags: ios, xcode, fastlane

After setting up [fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/) with mostly default settings I got an automated build and upload to iTunes Connect using gym's `export_method: "app-store"`. This uploads files to iTunes connect, and leaves in the current directory `*.app.dSYM.zip` and `*.ipa` files. However, when I open Xcode's organizer I don't see a build archive for the uploaded files.

Is it somehow possible to convert the files left by fastlane into an Xcode archive and have it appear in the organizer? Gym parameter documentation mentions [alternatives for the export_method parameter](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/#building): `ad-hoc, package, enterprise, development, developer-id`, but I have no idea what they mean or do.

**EDIT:** Since Fastlane is placing files in a hardcoded path I [opened an issue about this](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/8729).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't pass a `build_path` or `archive_path` to *gym* it should default to placing your archive into `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/[date]`. That is where Xcode looks for archives, so they should then be visible in the Organizer!

Comment: Ah, good to know. The reason it's not working for me is I have set a custom path in Xcode.